# Custom dialog delays app when loading long xml

Tags: android, performance, dialog

I have a dialog that when opened has about 12 tablelayouts with a lot of information. The complete XML for that dialog is about 10K lines of code and when I click it it takes about three seconds to open.

How do I solve this? I was thinking about maybe preloading the lwhole layout somehow, but I don't know if that will make things even worse. What I'm missing here?

Comment: That seems excessive for a dialog. Perhaps this should be split up over several screens. Alternatively, since the user cannot see all of that at once and needs to scroll, perhaps you can use `RecyclerView` so the content gets loaded progressively.

Comment: you can show the info bit by bit as the user scrolls using the paging library I guess, because I haven't used it myself or mabye add a limit to the query that you send to the sqlite db and use `limit` and `offset` to load data gradually

Comment: can you post the gist of the xml?

Comment: The problem is those tables exanse and collapse when pressed. There's only 12 tables, so not enough space for scrolling until one of them is pressed

Comment: you need to show your data in a different way, I suggest show the table names in a recycleriew and upon clicking the tablename show whats inside it in another recyclerview or a table. The user is expanding and seeing them one at a time anyway right?

Comment: u may use viewstub for tables and when a table is pressed, load its layout.